# What is the difference between 'sense-data' and 'facts'?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, terminology, semantics, empiricism, objectivity

There appear to be times when philosophers use these terms ['sense-data'](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data/) and ['facts'](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/) synonymously, and at other times as distinct entities. **Is there philosophy that speaks to characterize the relationship between them? Is there a simple difference between them?**

Comment: [Sense data](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sense-data/) is something like mental images, [facts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/) are what those are of, and they do not have to be directly sense related (if at all). Conservation of energy is a theoretical fact, for example, whatever makes Pythagorean theorem true is a mathematical fact. I doubt that anybody would use them synonymously, except in a loose elliptic way for sense facts.

Comment: I will disagree with Conifold here. SENSE DATA can Express IN SCIENCE the times we use our famous FIVE SENSES: sight, hearing, taste, smell & touch. This is what ALL SCIENCES must have to be a science in the first place. There are NO SCIENCES that are not physical in some way. Even the word PROOF or PROVE  appeals to at least one of the 5 senses. FACT outside of SCIENCE can Express things that are independently true in reality that never change truth value.  There is a good chance that is what some philosophers have meant NOT the science definition. Science is about the senses.No ducking this.

Comment: Great question. Did you have specific examples? Pay particular attention to the notion of [brute fact](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/#BrutFact) which are facts that seem to derive directly from sense-data. Some philosophers draw distinction between the social process of building facts and facts that seem self-evident.

Comment: Facts are valid propositions, propositions are elements of knowledge. But sense-data is information obtained from perception. There is a clear difference: sensing data (e.g. perceiving a lake) does not mean that the existence of the lake is a fact, you are perhaps experiencing a delusion. That is, in essence, what your references state, and they seem correct.

Comment: Can you give us a case or two of a philosopher using the terms 'sense-data' and 'facts' synonymously?   Or maybe the context(s) in which your recall them so used?  Or philosophical or scientific contexts in which such a confluence of ostensibly disparate terms is unavoidable given the thesis that is being put forward?

Comment: @gonzo- The disparate comments reflecting a few of the ambiguities in the usage of the two terms should answer your question.

Comment: That you answer my simple straightforward question obliquely speaks volumes.  So does this mean that you cannot answer my question re your comment that  "There appear to be times when philosophers use these terms 'sense-data' and 'facts' synonymously."  Give me a concrete example of such usage.

Comment: @gonzo- Whether a ' sense data' or a 'fact' any object or thing under consideration is not a 'given'. Whoever the Observer may be they do not 'absorb' either data or facts unfiltered. Any conclusion or hypothesis rendered by the Observer whether in a laboratory or any where else is an 'interpretation'. Beyond that it will also be an abstraction and involve no objective value whatsoever.

Comment: I think it would help to name at least one philosopher who seems to use them synonymously. It makes a reader curious to even have this considered, and for me, it is very disappointing to have this curiosity met with...nothing. No foundationalist I know of - and they are the ones who tend to try to use sense-data for epistemic justification - does that. They are careful to say that the sense-datum is eg. our *access* to factual knowledge because it corresponds directly to facts. Would you mind providing some hint where you got that idea from?

Comment: Hello Philip, See my answer below.

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders I've read that before asking. The problem is that "observed facts" tell us nothing about sense-data. Sense-data usually is understood to be the medium through which we observe facts, that's far from using them synonymously. I find this answer hardly appropriate to the question either way, especially as it lacks any kind of explanatory comment on how this ties together and does not use the terminology at all. If I read about sense-data and facts, I expect to read something about guys like Chisholm, who is like THE contemporary foundationalist.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it to some extent reduces to where these entities are thought to be "located."

Qualia-like sense data are generally considered to be located In ones mind,  in that they are "the alleged mind-dependent objects that we are directly aware of in perception, and that have exactly the properties they appear to have."  (See SEP).

Whereas "facts" (ala correspondence theory and its ilk), are something like states of affairs [out there]  known (how, and by whom?) to be true, to exist, or what is thought to be the case?  As Wittgenstein said in the **Tractatus,* trying to dissolve the issue:  "The facts in logical space are the world," (1.13).  And "The world divides into facts." (1.2)

Nevertheless, strictly speaking, there is the [inferential] leap from the "known" to exist (phenomena-sense data) to what actually exists (noumena-facts).  that is, it is only by inferring from one's available "sense data" that one can say whether the something is or is not a "fact."

Comment: So, it's about the dichotomy of the internal and the external in your view?

Comment: @ J D  If the complex relationship and distinctions between a 'fact' (as described by Wittgenstein) and a 'sense datum' is  to be made "simple", as the OP requires,  then I guess my answer to your question would be yes.

Comment: Thanks. I have been thinking a lot of the notion of the [brute fact](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/#BrutFact) and your answer seems to suggest that the 'bruteness' is a matter of location. Something to meditate upon, thanks.

Comment: @ J D No problemo.  BTW  Can you offer, as I asked the OP,  an case or two of a philosopher using the terms 'sense-data' and 'facts' synonymously."   Or maybe conceive of contexts in which they are so used? – Better: contexts in which such  confluence of disparate terms would be unavoidable?

Comment: I'll see if I can't tackle that.

Comment: Better yet:  ID philosophical or scientific contexts in which such a confluence of  these  ostensibly disparate terms is unavoidable, AND identify the thesis being put forward that makes the confluence inescapable while preserving its sense.

Comment: @gonza- Your comment on 'qualia' being both mind-dependent, therefore subjective and at the same time, and that 'have exactly the same properties that they 'appear' to cafe's, is incoherent. Which returns us to the 'problematic' nature of both 'sense data' and 'facts'. They are both entirely up to the individual perceiving them and therefore have no non-ambiguous philosophical interest.

Comment: As to the quoted language being incoherent, take it up with the editors of Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, which, you may have noticed, is where the quote came from.  Although I do not know what you mean by "cafe's."

Comment: @gonzo- Sorry this stupid unrequested 'corrector' on the site took over. Should be have.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a request made from a SEP member to see some documentation concerning any author who espouses that 'facts' and 'sense data' are treated as synonymous.

What follows is the full version from which I compacted my latest comment concerning the inherent difficulties with both facts and data as scientifically non-problematic.

This excerpt is from the Prolegomena, pp.24-25, under the heading, (i) Natural Causes Incoherent in Prof. HF Hallett's, "Creation, Emanation and Salvation".

See the bolded segment for the focused response to the member's request.

*"Similar difficulties have always haunted the causal theories of empiricist and positivistic thinkers; for spatial contiguity and temporal
succession cannot, without the surreptitious or overt introduction of
some factor which involves or insinuates agency, be made to yield a
relation even seemingly causal. The antecedent and the sequent must,
as such, be temporally separate, and thus distinct and disconnected;
and however narrow the interval may be taken to be, this disconnection
baffles the search for a causal relation of distinct essences. The attempt
to avoid this impasse by reducing the temporal gap to the ideal limit of
a mathematical section, the antecedent lying on one side, and the
sequent on the other, must fail because thus also antecedent and sequent
must approximate to identity. The defense of 'natural causation' thus
requires what ex hypothesi cannot be allowed, viz. the elimination of the
temporal disconnection of antecedent and sequent, the emendation of
the pulverulence of time. Nor is this alone sufficient in the absence of
some intelligible relation of essences between antecedent and sequent.
1 For this alternative see Kemp Smith, Philosophy of David Hume, chs xvi-xviii, App. If
this was indeed Hume's view, his restraint in making it known, and his failure to draw the
obvious conclusion, are perhaps natural but not the less regrettable.
PROLEGOMENA 25
For causation is not merely a process of durational transition, but involves necessity which must be founded in the natures of the antecedent
and sequent. It is little wonder, therefore, that empiricists and positivists
who resist the introduction of principles that transcend the schemata of
time and event reject the notion of natural causation, or, what is the
same thing, reduce it to a function of probabilities of succession taken
as statistically computed.
**In this connection we must note also what is generally overlooked by
those who take our knowledge as beginning from observed 'facts,'
'events,' or 'data,' and proceeding to principles and theories, that the
antecedent of any singular event taken strictly as singular is never a
single event but an indefinitely great mass of events. Even if we seek
to restrict these to those which are (in Lord Balfour's locution) 'relevant' the antecedent must remain extremely complicated and intellectually unwieldy. This complication is commonly mitigated or concealed by taking the events as singular in a special manner, viz. as
'instances' of a general kind, and thus named. When, therefore, we
speak of one event as causing another we are apt to think of the kinds
rather than the instances, and to suppose that one kind of event can be
the cause of another kind. But kinds, being abstract universals, cannot
be natural causes, and it is in their singularity that alone the instances
can operate. Yet however firmly we may grasp this principle it seems
impossible in this type of approach to avoid imputing to the instances
causal relations abstractly conceived as if they were the relations of the
kinds. But if a singular antecedent is to be properly causal its causality
must likewise be singular.** Its operation cannot be mere participation
in the impossible operation of its kind. Nor can this paradox be avoided
by conceiving the kind, not as an abstract universal but as an indefinite
set of singulars, and the causal relations of the members of two kinds
as no more than statistically computable probability of succession. For
if the members of the sets are genuine singulars the sequence of one
pair of members of two sets cannot depend on the manner in which
other pairs are related. Nor, it seems, do those who favour this way of
thinking suppose this - their object being to discredit the notion of
causation as operation rather than to make it intelligible."*